# AdColony Unity Plugin iOS video only once

Tags: ios, video, plugins, unity-game-engine, adcolony

i have setup adcolony right (i hope), it presents the video ad once then when i try to show the video again it shows this then don't show the video until i restart the app. I am using the AdColony unity plugin for iOS. does anyone knows what is about ? I don't understand very much of the xcode or objective c to solve this. many thanks.

```
2015-05-25 04:01:36.844 mygame[1472:60b] Warning: Attempt to present <ADCRotatingViewController: 0x19718630> on <ADCRootViewController: 0x1964f390> whose view is not in the window hierarchy! 2015-05-25 04:01:36.846 mygame[1472:60b] false|false|0|
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-Unity-SDK/pull/2

copy `UnityADC.mm` to `Assets/Plugins/iOS/UnityADC.mm` and build again.